# PHP & Mobile Sites

Tags: php, android, iphone, mobile, tablet

I'm just about to start a small mobile site that will be written in PHP. I am aware of the design principles of developing for mobiles, my question is more to do with the compatability of PHP on mobile devices. It is:

If I use PHP to make this mobile site (which will render in the client's mobile browser as good old HTML) will I run into any compatability problems?

As far as I can see, because PHP is a server side language, as long as it serves mobile friendly HTML, I should be able to do everything I please in PHP in my scripts? Is this correct? Or will iPhones, Android Mobiles and various Fondle Slabs refuse to render a xxx.php file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that it's a server-side technology. The browsers (whether mobile or desktop) will not care that it's PHP as it will never see anything but the html/js that is rendered from your PHP scripts.

Comment: brilliant, thank you for a quick answer! i guessed as much, just wondered if the .php extension on urls might throw some mobile browsers, but clearly not! once again, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You could use haskell (as long as it renders html) and still make it show on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned PHP is server side language, so there is no way it could possibly be cause of compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a scripting language that dynamically generates HTML.

So instead of creating a website from lots of static HTML files, a dynamic website generates the HTML when required - each time a user browses to a page the PHP is run on the server to create the HTML that is shown in the browser.

To answer your question, it is not the PHP that determines how sites look on mobile devices, more the HTML it generates :)